# How can I bind a variable in a map function to a type?

Tags: rust

How can I tell the compiler that this is a type that should have a function `pow()`?

```
pub fn is_armstrong_number(num: u32) -> bool {

  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].iter()
                             .zip( num.to_string().chars()
                             .map(|c| c.to_digit(10).unwrap()) )
                             .map(|(x, y)| *x.pow(y))
                             .fold(0, |acc, x| acc + x) == num

}
```

Error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `pow` found for type `&{integer}` in the current scope
  --> src/lib.rs:10:47
   |
10 |                              .map(|(x, y)| *x.pow(y))
   |                                               ^^^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, the compiler doesn't guess what the type of your integer is.

The compiler needs a hint:

```
pub fn is_armstrong_number(num: u32) -> bool {
    (1..10u32) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].iter()
        .zip(num.to_string().chars().map(|c| c.to_digit(10).unwrap()))
        .map(|(x, y)| x.pow(y))
        .sum::<u32>() // .fold(0, |acc, x| acc + x)
        == num
}
```

---

Also note that your implementation of armstrong_number is wrong, a correct one could be:

```
fn is_armstrong_number(num: u32) -> bool {
    let buf = num.to_string();
    let y = buf.chars().count() as u32;
    buf.chars()
        .map(|c| c.to_digit(10).unwrap())
        .map(|x| x.pow(y))
        .sum::<u32>()
        == num
}

fn main() {
    assert!(is_armstrong_number(153));
    assert!(!is_armstrong_number(11));
}
```

---

I also tried this one for fun:

```
extern crate num; // 0.2.0

#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct DigitInteger<T> {
    num: T,
    radix: T,
}

impl<T> Iterator for DigitInteger<T>
where
    T: num::Unsigned + num::Zero + Copy,
{
    type Item = T;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.num != T::zero() {
            let ret = self.num % self.radix;
            self.num = self.num / self.radix;
            Some(ret)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

fn is_armstrong_number<T>(num: T, radix: T) -> bool
where
    T: num::Unsigned,
    T: num::pow::Pow<T>,
    T: num::FromPrimitive,
    T: std::iter::Sum<<<DigitInteger<T> as std::iter::Iterator>::Item as num::traits::Pow<T>>::Output>,
    T: Copy,
{
    use num::pow::Pow;
    let d = DigitInteger { num, radix };
    let y = T::from_usize(d.count()).unwrap();
    d.map(|x| Pow::pow(x, y)).sum::<T>() == num
}

fn main() {
    assert!(is_armstrong_number(153u32, 10));
    assert!(!is_armstrong_number(11u32, 10));
    assert!(is_armstrong_number(1u32, 2));
    assert!(!is_armstrong_number(2u32, 2));
}
```

Comment: Or even better, `(1..10u32).zip...`.

Answer (score 2):

You can cast with `as`.

Change

```
.map(|(x, y)| *x.pow(y))
```

to

```
.map(|(x, y)| (*x as u32).pow(y))
```

Comment: This is a great answer thanks, and the exact question I had in mind

Comment: `warning: casting u8 to u32 may become silently lossy if types change` => `help: try: 'u32::from(x)'` I think this clippy lint is awesome <3

Comment: @hellow I answered the explicit question but I totally agree that stargateur's answer better solves OP's real problem here

Comment: I didn't say anything against your answer, it is simple and clear. I just said something about the `as` cast, because IMHO it is better to use `u32::from` instead.